# How read/write data on my laptop BIOS?

Tags: c#, winforms, url-rewriting, bios

Is it possible to read/write the BIOS of my laptop? I want to grab my BIOS file with **rom** or **bin** extension. we can easily get bios information, but how can we grab/downlaod bios chipset file?

Comment: The way I get it this is something that the BIOS manufacturer would like to protect. They don't want you to easily be able to write to the BIOS,, imagine what a malicious program could do if it could write to bios?
I might be wrong, but would be very surprised if it was easy.

Comment: Ok, I thought you're interested in SMBIOS data. To map BIOS memory and read it, you need to run your code in ring 0. So you need either write device driver or use existing one (general purpose driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at win32 api function [GetSystemFirmwareTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724379(v=vs.85).aspx).

**edit:**

Above is valid for reading SMBIOS data. To read actual BIOS memory, code need to be run in kernel mode.

Comment: You need to write kernel mode driver that will read memory where BIOS is mapped. Then you need to load that driver in user mode (your application) and use IOCTL to comunicate with your driver and get data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @MoonLight, how do i connect u, i have similar question and need used your experience this topic.

Comment: @MoonLight your problem is solved, if it solved please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Win32_BIOS WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) class that you will be able to instantiate and query through methods in the System.Management namespace. I don't know specifically if this class has a property for BIOS chipset - if not, you could maybe look at Win32_Processor although this is designed to return information on the CPU, not the BIOS.